# Power Isolation generating error in KiCAD

Tags: power, kicad, error, ferrite-bead, drc

I've created a ferrite bead part with two passive pins. When I insert it in a power line, it causes an error "ErrType(3): Pin connected to some others pins but no pin to drive it" Changing the pins to bidirectional or unspecified has no effect. Using an inductor provides the same error message. Is the only way to avoid this error to redefine the pins as power in and out?

This is Eeschema version 2013-07-07 BZR 4022 - stable for Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you get the error at all the power in pins of your circuit: you are not providing them a power out connection since your power line is in series with the ferrite bead, which is passive/passive.

If you want to keep your filter symmetric, and it is symmetric, you can use the power flag. The power flag is basically a fake power output pin, where fake means it has no real counterpart. You place it on nets you know are powered to tell the DRC all is fine.

You can find the power flag component in the 'place power port' menu.

Comment: I thought I thanked you, but see that I had not. This was the advice I needed.